# "Add Two Numbers" JavaScript Leetcode error

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodes

I am getting errors in my leetcode and I am not sure why:

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
let newL1 = []
let newL2 = []
let answer = []

for(let i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
    newL1[i] = l1[l1.length - 1 - i]
}

for(let i = 0; i < l2.length; i++) {
    newL2[i] = l2[l2.length - 1 - i]
}

let num = parseInt(newL1.toString().replace(/,/g, '')) + parseInt(newL2.toString().replace(/,/g, ''))

let rawAnswer = (num.toString().split(""))

for(let i=0; i < rawAnswer.length; i++) {
    answer[i] = parseInt(rawAnswer[i])
}

return answer
```

}

Error:

```
Line 45 in solution.js
             throw new TypeError(__serialize__(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode");
             ^
TypeError: null is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode
    Line 45: Char 20 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 29: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 1251: Char 30 in loader.js (Module._compile)
    Line 1272: Char 10 in loader.js (Object.Module._extensions..js)
    Line 1100: Char 32 in loader.js (Module.load)
    Line 962: Char 14 in loader.js (Function.Module._load)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    Line 17: Char 47 in run_main_module.js
```

Challenge Description:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Example:

```
Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,0,8]
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error, but I know I am doing something that leetcode doesn't like.

Thanks

Comment: The error says it was expecting a `ListNode` object.  But looks like you're returning a number.

Comment: I haven't examined your logic, but you're returning a number (equivalent of 807 in the example), when you're supposed to return it as a list of digits

Comment: I believe you are attempting:  https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Comment: Why did you delete the old question and started a new one?

Comment: @Wyck You're right. I just fixed it. The problem is with the initial for loop though. The answer returned from let code though is [nan, nan, nan]. I'm running it through vscode and I get the correct answer, so I'm just not sure what part of my syntax is throwing leetcode off.

Comment: @B001ᛦ It was an accident. Stackoverflow was giving me a hard time with the way I had my code laid out so I wiped it then accidentally posted it. I probably should have just updated that one. My bad.

Comment: You are not returning an object of type `ListNode`.  Leetcode provides this: 
 `function ListNode(val) { this.val = val; this.next = null; }`  And you should have `new ListNode(.....)` in your code to create the nodes of the linked list.  You've completely ignored all that in your solution.

Comment: I am pretty sure you shouldnt be iterating over listNode like that, you should be provided with ListNode definition somewhere in your description i reckon, can you share that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description reads: `return the sum as a linked list`

You're doing two `parseInt` and returning the sum (that is a number) but it should return a linked list instead, defined by the head of the list (the first `ListNode` object.

Comment: You're right. I just fixed it. The problem is with the initial for loop though. The answer returned from let code though is [nan, nan, nan]. I'm running it through vscode and I get the correct answer, so I'm just not sure what part of my syntax is throwing leetcode off.

Comment: You're still returning a list of numbers. You have to return a `ListNode` object.

Comment: Okay y'all are right I didn't even notice that. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
        let k=new ListNode(0,null);
        let k1= k;
        let x,y,c=0;
        while(l1!=null || l2!=null){
            x = l1!=null?l1.val:0;
            y = l2!=null?l2.val:0;
            c=x+y+c;
            k1.next =new ListNode(c%10,null);
            k1 = k1.next ;
            c=parseInt(c/10);
            if(l1!=null) l1=l1.next ;
            if(l2!=null) l2=l2.next ;
        }
        
        if(c>0) {
            k1.next=new ListNode(c,null);
            k1=k1.next ;
        }
      
        return k.next;

};
```

**ListNode this function .**

1. value.next - next item
2. value.val  - the value of that element

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution:

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
  const sum = convertArrayStringToNumber(l1) + convertArrayStringToNumber(l2);
  return sum === 0? [0]: sum.toString().split("");
};

var convertArrayStringToNumber = function(arrayNumber) {
  if (arrayNumber.length === 1) return arrayNumber[0];
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = arrayNumber.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sum += arrayNumber[i]*Math.pow(10, I);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate how your code solves the issue of the question. An answer should always include information about how the provided code solves the issue. Please use the **Edit** option to do this. Also please read this: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).